# How to insert the form arrays from URL to DBD database using perl script?

Tags: perl, postgresql, psql

I am trying to get the data filled in the html to DBD database using perl script.

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
</head>


<body>
<H1>Friend's contact book</H1>

<FORM ACTION="contact.pl" METHOD="POST">


<HR>
<H2>Friend's contact</H2>

<PRE>
          Name:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name"> 
         Address:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="add"> 


</PRE>

</HR><P>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Sign Up"> or <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Cancel">
</P>
</FORM>
</body></html>
```

Here is my perl script:
contact.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Initialize DBI.
use DBI;
use strict;

# Make the database connection.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=friendcontact") 
or die my $DBI::errstr;

   # Store the SQL query

myy $stat = my $dbh->prepare("INSERT into friend (name, add) VALUE 
(?,?)");

   # Execute the query

my $stmh->execute();

   # Tidy up

my $stmh->finish();
my $dbh->commit or die my $DBI::errstr;
```

I could not run the **contact.pl** code 
It said **"Internal Server Error"**

Is there anyway I could correct this?

Thanks alot in advance

Thank you
I had already edited the code as you said but it is having error with
After **updating:**
    Internal Server Error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Premature end of script headers: /home/friendcontact/private/cgi-bin/contact.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to get your Perl errors directed to the browser so that you can debug. This is the usual way, though it's hard to know without seeing the CGI part of your code:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

You also may need to change setting on your server.

Beyond that, there are several problems here. I believe this needs `VALUES` rather than `VALUE`:

```
$stat = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT into friend (name, add) VALUE 
(?,?)");
```

Also, this is incorrect:

```
$stmh->execute('$name','$add');
```

When using the `?` placeholders with DBH, you don't need to quote your variables; it handles that for you internally.  Even allowing for that, you used single quotes, which means that you aren't passing in the variables, but just the literal strings `'$name'` and `'$add'`.  Just do this instead:

```
$stmh->execute($name,$add);
```

That is just a start; there is probably more here.

**Update:** You are also getting errors because you have not declared variables before using them.  You should declare each variable using the form `my $var;`.  This makes it a lexical variable, rather than a global one.  This is good practice, and because you say `use strict;` (a very good thing to do), it is also a required practice.

Comment: Thanks alot
I had edited as you said
and listed the error list given by the browser

Comment: thank you for your comments but after changing all the variables, it happens to have internal error

Comment: @userpane, that is a generic error message that means your script didn't send any output to the server.  It could be that you are having a failure early in the compilation.  Or it could be that your script is succeeding, but you aren't sending any html output.  To test the latter case, try putting `die "Script finished!";` at the end of your script.  If you get that message in your browser, that means you succeeded, you just need to return some output.  If you don't get the message, it is some other error--there is no easy way of knowing what it is.

Comment: I had put the `die "Script finished!";` it is showing as this **`Software error:

Script finished! at /home/friendcontact/private/cgi-bin/contact.pl line.`**

Comment: is that the one which is supposed to get?

Answer (score 0):

You don't `do` a prepared handle. Just prepare and execute:

```
$stat = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT into friend (name, add) VALUES(?,?)" );
$stat->execute( $name, $add);
```

And I'm assuming you've got other code which sets the `$name` and `$add` variables, because it won't happen automatically.

Edit: You had other issues too. Don't quote the variables in the call to `execute`. And its `VALUES` in the insert statement